# Apply collision collection to a group?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

How do I link a group of 100 objects to same collision collection? I don't want to do it manually and ctrl+l link modifiers / collections doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution - select all objects, make the object with desired settings active and do f3 and type copy rigid body settings.

Comment: Hello :) You can also use *RMB > Move to collection* :)